# PHP - echo con contenido que tiene comilla doble y comilla sencilla

Tags: php

Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer el siguiente echo en PHP

```
echo '<img class="imgfit img" src="img/evento/3-thumb.jpg" onclick="window.location.href="img/evento/3.jpg"" style="border-radius:0;" alt="">';
```

El dilema que tengo está en que al usar `window.location.href` hay que usar comilla única o doble, entonces cómo puedo resolver el problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías simplemente hacer un "escape" de las comillas del elemento en mención y utilizar comillas simples, como en tu caso:

```
onclick="window.location.href=\'img/evento/3.jpg\'"
```